# New issue on previously stable docksal implementations

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb, docksal

I've been developing two sites using docksal on a macbook m1 for weeks without any issues. Today, one site still allows me to access it, but running drush sqlc results in an endless flood of:

```
Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: 192.168.64.1:9000 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port)
```

When I run

```
fin exec php -v | grep -i xdebug
```

I get

```
fin exec php -v | grep -i xdebug
    with Xdebug v3.1.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2022, by Derick Rethans
```

and php is configured to use xdebug on 9000. There doesn't seem to be anything listening to that port.

The other site does not let me access it, returning this in addition a few of the xdebug complaint when I try to access the db:

```
The command "mysql --defaults-file=/tmp/drush_ew45Y0 --database=default --host=db --port=3306 -A" failed.  
                                                                                                             
  Exit Code: 1(General error)                                                                                
                                                                                                             
  Working directory: /var/www/web                                                                            
                                                                                                             
  Output:                                                                                                    
  ================                                                                                           
                                                                                                             
                                                                                                             
  Error Output:                                                                                              
  ================
```

Docker PS says all containers are healthy.

The versions are:

- Docker Desktop 4.9.1 (81317)
- Docksal 1.16
- PHP 8.1
- Xdebug 3.1.4
- MySql Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.5.15-MariaD

In Docker, the log for the db container (which stops running as soon as it starts) is:

```
runtime stack:

runtime.throw(0x524da0, 0x9)

/usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:527 +0x90

runtime.newosproc(0xc82002a000, 0xc820039fc0)

/usr/local/go/src/runtime/os1_linux.go:150 +0x1ab

runtime.newm(0x555ce8, 0x0)

/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc1.go:1105 +0x130

runtime.main.func1()

/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:48 +0x2c

runtime.systemstack(0x5c4300)

/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:262 +0x79

runtime.mstart()

/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc1.go:674


goroutine 1 [running]:

runtime.systemstack_switch()

/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:216 fp=0xc820024770 sp=0xc820024768

runtime.main()

/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:49 +0x62 fp=0xc8200247c0 sp=0xc820024770

runtime.goexit()

/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1696 +0x1 fp=0xc8200247c8 sp=0xc8200247c0

Running init scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/ as root...

Including custom configuration from /var/www/.docksal/etc/mysql/my.cnf

Running init scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/ as root...

Including custom configuration from /var/www/.docksal/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

And the Inspection info is:

```
Environment
MYSQL_ONETIME_PASSWORD

MYSQL_INITDB_SKIP_TZINFO

MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
root

MYSQL_USER
user

MYSQL_PASSWORD
user

MYSQL_DATABASE
default

MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD

MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD

PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

GOSU_VERSION
1.7

MYSQL_MAJOR
5.7

MYSQL_VERSION
5.7.25-1debian9

Mounts
/VAR/LIB/MYSQL
/var/lib/docker/volumes/pii_db_data/_data

/VAR/WWW
/var/lib/docker/volumes/pii_project_root/_data

Port
3306/tcp
0.0.0.0:0
```

Comment: I spent hours trying various things suggested, diving down numerous rabbit holes. Finally, I renamed the 2 site folders to <site>.borked, reinstalled Docker for silicon, cloned docksal for composer d9 into each, installed contrib I need, copied in my custom work, and all is well again.